# Finding some conditional probabilities in FiveThiryEight's College Football Playoff prediction model

Tags: probability

The new [College Football Playoff](http://www.collegefootballplayoff.com) comprises two semifinal games and one final game. In this inaugural season, Alabama will face Ohio State and Oregon will face Florida State in the semifinals. The winners of those two games will meet in the final game, which will determine the championship.

[On December 7, FiveThirtyEight's playoff model](http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/college-football-playoff-final-thoughts-and-national-championship-odds/) gave the following probabilities for each team to reach the final round (i.e. win their semifinal game):

```
Oregon         0.651
Alabama        0.592
Ohio State     0.408
Florida State  0.349
```

FiveThiryEight's model gave the following probabilities for each team to win the championship:

```
Oregon         0.354
Alabama        0.321
Ohio State     0.188
Florida State  0.137
```

Assuming these probabilities, what is the conditional probability that:

- Oregon wins the championship, given that Oregon and Alabama play in the final round?
- Oregon wins the championship, given that Oregon and Ohio State play in the final round?

Comment: N.B. these probabilities appear to be from FiveThirtyEight's forecast http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/college-football-playoff-final-thoughts-and-national-championship-odds/

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information to answer, though you can make a reasonable assumption that gives you an answer.  If Oregon makes the finals, their chance of winning is $\frac {0.354}{0.651}=0.544$  It could be they have $\frac {0.544}{0.592}=0.919$ chance of beating Alabama and no chance at all against Florida State.  It could be they would be sure to beat Florida State and they have $\frac {0.544-0.349}{0.592}=0.329$ chance against Alabama.  The simplest assumption would be that Oregon has the same chance against Alabama and Florida State, which would be $0.544$.  I'm sure that FiveThirtyEight's model has an answer, but the data presented here don't give it.